# Can I increase or decrease Postgres DB ec2 instance class type dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am using postgres db in AWS-RDS with instanceClass = "db.m4.4xlarge" in terraform.

Now i want to increase/decrease (auto-scaling) instanceClass by using DB size or any other parameters. It should be auto scaled when postgres db size reached it's limit.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: When you are saying db size, do you want to increase or decrease the storage?

Comment: @MohitKumar i want to increase/decrease instanceClass for my postgres db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can not increase or decrease your instance size like this, you will have to bear downtime to [modify RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html) instance type.

But you can scale based on load but scaling will be of the same instance type not like the one you want with different instance type.

You can achieve your objective using [postgresql-serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-aurora-postgresql-serverless-now-generally-available/) which scale up and down based on desired metrics.

You need to specify the maximum and minimum resources the Serverless RDS can scale up to

[amazon-aurora-postgresql-serverless-scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-aurora-postgresql-serverless-now-generally-available/).

[image]

Comment: How we can scale up and down instanceClass based on load with the same instance type?

Comment: Scaling based on changing instance class type not really good practice and you can do this using cloudwatch plus lamda function but that approch can never be accpeted in production and  I will never recommend where you will bear downtime so what I will suggest to `serverless`  so you will not need worry about instance type you just to focus on application.

Comment: Yes, I gone through with **serverless** it's very interesting and we can achieve  scale up and down.

Comment: Glad to know :) and I prefer serverless in some cases

Comment: If we talk about pricing so, serverless is very costly.
That's why I am preferring scale up and down for reduce the cost. I have checked for aurora database serverless it's quite costly as compare to **postgres engine**. I am little confused in both :) 
Is there any way where we can achieve scaling feature with reduce cost?

Comment: I think you can reduce cost serverless better specifically in production and where load is not consistent.

Comment: We are going to use **serverless**. But before using i have a small question.
Currently we are using RDS with postgress db and db has huge amount of data, while replacing **RDS postgress** with **serverless postgress** data migration is required from old db to new db?

Comment: I think you can restore from snapshot if the version is same